# Cantilever stress hotspots and making it stronger

Tags: structural-engineering

This is a simplified 2d version of a davit arm + arch I'm trying to create for a boat.

I'm having problems with the stress hot spots from the cantilever. How can I make this stronger?

The image is the basic stainless tube frame (deformed). A small boat is pulled up underneath which limits angles underneath the cantilever.

I'm trying to aim at a weight of 100kg but a bigger safety factor is better of course, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

[image: Frame]

Comment: The leg support to the deck connection will be most critical. The first thing to do is pin down the lever arm distance from the lift point to the support. M = P*L.

Comment: Maximum stress at the top is caused by two beam at an angle loaded in tension. You could replace these by one straight beam or use an elbow (bent tube might be ok).

Comment: Instead of frame, you might consider truss structure (basically triangular pattern), which leads to loading in tension/compression and decreases bending stresses. You are already using this in the top left part.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the maximum stresses you are seeing, are probably artifacts of the simulations.

However if you wanted to lower the stresses on that particular corner you could try an reinforcement like the following.

[image]